# Web API Response For a Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I Simply Create a Web API in ASP.NET and API call in ROKU using **"roUrlTransfer"**. Here blow my while Condition my Response Required For around 1 minutes. But here wait for only 20 seconds. Its Possible to wait 1 minutes For Response in ROKU.

First I Create a Response Like Below.
`readdata = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")` and set url here `readdata.setUrl(data)`

```
while(true)
   msg = Wait(0, m.port) ' here only 30000 millisecond pause
'  statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode()   ' check status code is working or not           
   if (type(msg) = "roUrlEvent")
      ?"event display here"
      statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode()
      headers = msg.GetResponseHeaders()
      if msg.getresponsecode() = 200 then
         data = msg.getstring()
         headers = msg.getresponseheadersarray()
         print "***************HEADERS******************"
         for each header in headers
             print header
         end for
         print "***************DATA*********************"
         print data
         print "****************************************"
         ?"statusCode value here : " statusCode
         exit while
       else
          readInternet.asynccancel()
          ?"here not valid username and password"
       end if
    else
       ? "do somthing useful while we wait for data"
    end if
end while
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls, `statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode()` print in console if found "200" then completely getting response. Someone will put to a breakpoint in the web server and try to hold a response. But It's not possible in Roku Side. you can only manage around a 20-sec response in Roku. Pls, try to reduce response time in your server.

Comment: ok I will try. I check 15 sec response It's successfully handle.

Comment: that's cool pls, try to reduce your response time in your server. which technology did you use for creating a web server?

Comment: I used in .net core. But I have fetch 200 xml in my web server.

Comment: ok 200 XML fine.You have made it static? OR you have to get data from somewhere?

Comment: I found data in some another server. But Its response given in Browser. First I donwndload then I create my response.

Comment: I think you used the build-in method for download data. that's why download time takes high. pls, find another way to like first fetch string and put it into a file.